# nginx - how to have proxy pass render a subdomain on the page?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, vercel, nginx-location, proxypass

We have a PHP server with Nginx running. On a separate server hosted by Vercel we have a Next.js app running. We've deployed the Vercel app to a subdomain of our main domain: https://vercel.employbl.com/ Our domain is hosted by Cloudflare and we linked it to Vercel by adding a CNAME record like so:

[image: cname record cloudflare vercel]

What I'm trying to do is have our main jobs page instead Render the jobs page of the Vercel app. So user enters https://www.employbl.com/jobs but the Next.js app with the matching path https://vercel.employbl.com/jobs renders instead while keeping "employbl.com/jobs" as the URL.

This is the Nginx config we have currently using `proxy_pass`. Unfortunately I'm getting a 404 error from Vercel when I navigate to "employbl.com/jobs" using this Nginx config:

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  location /jobs {
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_pass https://vercel.employbl.com/jobs;
  }
```

This renders the page from Vercel: `404 - Code: DEPLOYMENT_NOT_FOUND` but the site is working at the URL provided in the nginx config.

How can I configure Nginx so that when the user navigates to "employbl.com/jobs" the https://vercel.employbl.com/jobs page renders?

Comment: I think that you should remove the CNAME and then serve `vercel.employbl.com` from your nginX - with a separate `server` block which uses `location /` with `proxy_pass` to `cname.vercel-dns.com`. So when the user navigates to `vercel.employbl.com/jobs` he will reach your nginX which will in turn proxy this request to Vercel. Thus you will ensure that `vercel.employbl.com/jobs` actually leads to `cname.vercel-dns.com/jobs` without your users noticing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up getting it working like this. Needed a separate entry to point to files for the `_next` directory that holds our assets. I think the primary fix was having `resolver 8.8.8.8;`

```
  location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
  }
  location /jobs {
     resolver 8.8.8.8;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass https://vercel.employbl.com/jobs;
  }
  location ~ ^/_next/(.*)$ {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass https://vercel.employbl.com/_next/$1;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, with trailing slash after the location directive (`/jobs/`). Then take `/jobs` off the proxy URL. I think your location path `/jobs` is being handed to the `proxy_pass` and ending up doubling the `/jobs/` part somehow. Because with no trailing slash it passes that forward. So try:

```
location /jobs/ {
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_pass https://vercel.employbl.com; #removed jobs 
}
```

**Edit:** *On my server I can only get it to work this way.* Both location directive and proxy URL end in a slash. From what I've read, this should make it drop the location directive path, instead of passing it on.

```
location /jobs/ {
 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
 proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
 proxy_pass https://vercel.employbl.com/jobs/;
}
```